# Update comment for sql server error at ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table `Seatlist` in SQL Server :

```
FlightNo     Origin   1      2     3
---------------------------------------
AK511        PEN      NULL   3     NULL
AK576        KUL      4      7     NULL
```

Below is my update query:

```
SqlCommand cmdupdate = new SqlCommand ("update Seatlist 
                                           set 2 = " + SeatNo.Text.ToString() + 
                                       " where ((FlightNo='" + FlightNo.Text.ToString() + "') 
                                           and (Origin='" + Origin.Text.ToString() + "'))", con);

cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have try below query also:

```
SqlCommand cmdupdate = new SqlCommand ("update Seatlist 
                                           set 2 = @seat 
                                         where ((FlightNo='" + FlightNo.Text.ToString() + "') 
                                           and (Origin='" + Origin.Text.ToString() + "'))", con);

cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"seat", SeatNo.Text);
```

But I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '2'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Comment: Try `Update Seatlist set [2] = `

Comment: I have try but same error i get, i have try put all bracket also same error

Comment: You do not follow the rules for [regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017) so you need to delimit those names with square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid string concatenation using the the raw input values. You open the door for [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), one of the most common ways that someone can use to compromise your a web app. You should use only parameterized queries.

The problem with your query relies on the usage of the 2 as a column name. Since 2 is a [delimited inentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017), you should make use of brackets as below:

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Seatlist " +
                     "SET [2] = @Seat " +
                     "WHERE FlightNo = @FlightNo AND Origin = @Origin";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

    command.Paramters.AddWithValue("@Seat", SeatNo.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FlightNo", FlightNo.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Origin", Origin.Text);

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: But unfortunately you use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - don't use it.

Comment: A better answer would have explained what actually caused the issue and how to resolve it. The problem was caused by the use of column names that violate the rules for regular identifiers. In addition, your parameterization code is incorrect with respect to the first (@seat) and third (@Origin) parameters.

Comment: @Smor Thanks for the link. I will check it. Also thanks for pointing my fault, I just corrected it.

Comment: @SMor If you have another answer and you think that it is better than this one, I would suggest you post it, since you will help both the OP and the readers of this post. Just my 2 cents.